# How to extract both deeply and shallowly nested fields in array of json objects

Tags: javascript, json, nested, iterator, data-extraction

Let's say I have this json object:

```
{
    "lotOfJson": [
    {
        "value": "someName",
        "property": "name",
        "children": [],
        "constraints": {
            "IsValidName": "name someName isn't valid"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": [
            {
                "id": "firstBadId"
            },
            {
                "id": "secondBadId"
            }
        ],
        "property": "listOfIds",
        "children": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "firstBadId"
                },
                "property": "0",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": "firstBadId",
                        "property": "id",
                        "children": [],
                        "constraints": {
                            "badIdError": "This Id is bad!"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "secondBadId"
                },
                "property": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": "secondBadId",
                        "property": "id",
                        "children": [],
                        "constraints": {
                            "badIdError": "This Id is bad"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
```

This array can have deeply nested JSON--there's no way of knowing how deep.

Whenever there's a block that looks like:

```
"value": "",
"property": "",
"children": [],
"constraints": {
    "": ""
}
```

I want to extract the values for `value`, `property` and `constraints` and save them in an array. For my `"lotsOfJson"` example above, this would look like:
`["someName", "name", "name SomeName isn't valid", "firstBadId, "id", "This Id is bad!", "secondBadId, "id", "This Id is bad!"]`

So I'm only extracting the value, property and constraints when they are parallel like in the block right above.

I could agnostically extract all the `value`,`property` and `constraints` that are in the JSON array using an iterator for instance, but is there a way to extract them only when the appear parallel to each other?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Your source *JSON* is poorly formatted and your target properties (`value`, `property`, `constraints`) are not uniform - they can take a value of a string, object or array in different parts of the source. If that's just a result of clumsy attempt to obfuscate source data, please, make a better sample to play with, if you need to get relevant answers. In general, simple recursive function is supposed to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create recursive function for this using `for...in` loop and only add to the result when the current object have no elements in the `children` array.

```js
const data = [{"value":"someName","property":"name","children":[],"constraints":{"IsValidName":"name someName isn't valid"}},{"value":[{"id":"firstBadId"},{"id":"secondBadId"}],"property":"listOfIds","children":[{"value":{"id":"firstBadId"},"property":"0","children":[{"value":"firstBadId","property":"id","children":[],"constraints":{"badIdError":"This Id is bad!"}}]},{"value":{"id":"secondBadId"},"property":"1","children":[{"value":"secondBadId","property":"id","children":[],"constraints":{"badIdError":"This Id is bad"}}]}]}]

function extract(data, fields) {
  let result = []

  for (let i in data) {
    if (typeof data[i] == 'object') {
      result.push(...extract(data[i], fields))
    }

    if (data.children && !data.children.length) {
      if (fields.includes(i)) {
        result = result.concat(
          typeof data[i] == 'object' ?
          Object.values(data[i]) :
          data[i]
        )
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const result = extract(data, ['property', 'value', 'constraints'])
console.log(result)
```